# How to see the logs of a worker container when using Kubernetes Executor in Airflow (not UI)

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, logz.io

I have a deployment of `Airflow` using the Kubernetes Executor storing logs onto a persistent volume, the logs are readable from the UI.

The issue is that with this configuration I can't see the logs in the pod using

```sh
kubectl logs -f <pod_name>
```

Is there a way to have the logs in both places?

My end goal is to have them in the Airflow UI and in my observability platform (logz.io)

Comment: not confident enough to post this as an answer, I think that you could specify multiple handlers to write logs to both the console and to a persistent location (there's a little info from astronomer [here](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/logging))

Comment: This is a really good resource but if I'm understanding correctly by default some things go to stdout/console while others go to a file. But from the documentation and that document I don't feel confident about changing it to achieve my goal.